# Asking questions to the user based on results of previous questions

Tags: algorithms

I have to select a question that would help me make me sure the user knows about a given subject.

As an example, let's assume the user hasn't answered any question yet. Every question has a scope (subject).

The system gives him/her a question that has 2 answers for him/her to choose. One of them is the right one. If the user picks the wrong one, later on the system will ask a question of the same subject to this user (it may not be the very next one, though). On the other hand, if the user picks the right one there won't be any questions about that subject anymore (although this changes slightly - take a look ahead).

There are some things to consider, though:

1. The user might forget things about a subject. Meaning that the questions about that subject should start reappearing.
2. When the user starts getting all the answers right, the question WILL appear but not with the same frequency (that's due to item 1).

There are two algorithms I want to develop:

1. The best way to choose a question based on what the user must have knowledge of. That's determined by the "how much he knows" and a factor of the subject's relevance.
2. An equation to calculate how many points the user has to compete with other people that take the same tests.

If you want an example of this working I would point out [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/). It has a system to fill some progress bars of lessons you passed. But if you get a question about the subject you already learned those progress bars would lower.

Any tips?